# delphi dll-finalization: how to debug

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll, dcom, finalize

I have a problem in a dll (including a COM object): when the dll is unloaded some finalization sections are executed and some are not.

in the debugger I could manage to locate the problem in System FinalizeUnits(). pseudo code of this function - for your convenience:

```
procedure FinalizeUnits;
var
  Count: Integer;
  Table: PUnitEntryTable;
  P: Pointer;
begin
  if InitContext.InitTable = nil then
    exit;
  Count := InitContext.InitCount;
  Table := InitContext.InitTable^.UnitInfo;
  try
    while Count > 0 do
    begin
      Dec(Count);
      InitContext.InitCount := Count;
      P := Table^[Count].FInit;
      if Assigned(P) and Assigned(Pointer(P^)) then
      begin
        // ISSUE: when this is called for item x the debugging just stops
        // breakpoints in the except block or at the end of the function are not reached!
        TProc(P)(); 
      end;
    end;
  except
    FinalizeUnits;  { try to finalize the others }
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

there is one specific finalization call that causes the problem:
i.e. the `InitContext.InitCount` is about 400 and when item x (e.g. 363) is executed, the debugger just stops: it does not proceed to the except block and also not to the end of the `FinalizeUnits()` function (where I have set breakpoints).
BTW: how is that possible? I thought the except block (or the line after it) must be called in any case.

notes:

- when I manually avoid this special call, all other functions are executed normally.
- when I step into the problematic `TProc` I end up in `TCriticalSection.Enter` (then `Acquire` - `FSection.Enter` - `EnterCriticalSection` - `WSACleanup`)

some more info to the `WSACleanup` call: I use a 3rd party library UniDAC that opens a TCP/IP connection to a database - I think this library calls `WSACleanup` in one of it's finalization sections (but I don't have this source code).
The strange thing is, that when the debugger is on the `WSACleanup` line:

```
function WSACleanup;        external     winsocket name 'WSACleanup';
```

and I want to step over it (i.e. F8), the debugger just stops (as if the application had exited normally) - but it should continue the loop in `FinalizeUnits`: how is this possible? i.e. if it were a deadlock it would not stop, but hang forever, right?

The question is: how can I debug this issue? is it possible that a deadlock causes this problem (i.e. that the debugger just stops)?

Comment: " .. end up in TCriticalSection.Enter " - It doesn't go anywhere from there?

Comment: "I thought the except block"  You're probably thinking of the finally block.  I see you've had an answer with a good suggestion, & knowing what a pain it is trying to debug into FinalizeUnits, I just wanted to check that you're aware you can set a "Pass count" on a breakpoint by right-clicking the red dot in the gutter and going to "Breakpoint properties ..."

Comment: Enable debug dcus and find out which unit the problem is in. Then work out why you have a deadlock.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: there are some more calls (now shown in the question)

Comment: @MartynA: sorry, my statement about the except block was not clear: I meant, it should go into the except block or to the line after it (I've updated the question now) - but as David Heffernan pointed out, this may be due to a deadlock.
I have used the breakpoint properties to stop if "Count = 363" - thanks for the hint.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: debug dcu's are enabled, other wise I could not step into the System unit, right? I thought maybe there's an easy way to find out to which unit the "P" function belongs to - the `InitContext.InitTable.TypeInfo.UnitNames` property looks promising - but how to use it?

Comment: AFAICT in the stock units only web.win.sockets terminates winsock (1.1) in a finalization section.

Comment: Well, when you step into the finalization you'll land in that unit's code.

Comment: Since it is a 3rd party lib I didn't have the source code. But in the meantime I managed to make a very simple example where I can reproduce the problem and have reported it to their support. Thanks for all the input here.

Comment: update: it turned out that it was not a problem of the 3rd party lib, but something related to my development machine. in the end I completely reinstalled windows, delphi, etc. and now it works (with the same source code on the same machine...)

Answer (score 2):

Try switching to CPU view before stepping into the problematic TProc using F7. Sometimes this can give you a good hint.

You could also try looking up the address of "P" in the map file.